# Jest - TypeError: Object(...) is not a function

Tags: javascript, jestjs

I have just started writing some integration tests, but Jest seems to be throwing this error:

```
tidee-air:tidee-life-web joe$ npx jest login-page.integration.test.js
 FAIL  src/pages/login/__tests__/login-page.integration.test.js
  ● Test suite failed to run

    TypeError: Object(...) is not a function

      93 |  * Copyright (c) 2014-2017, Jon Schlinkert.
      94 |  * Released under the MIT License.
      ...
```

When I also build my application using Webpack there aren't any errors. I have looked around for an answer to this and have added `@babel/polyfill` to the `setupFiles` section of my Jest configuration, but this hasn't made any difference. I'm really not sure what to do now.

Comment: The error seems to indicate it comes from your test suite, not your production code. This would be why Webpack doesn't get an error. What does the test suite code look like?

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can do now to gather more information is set breakpoints.

*[Tests are Failing and You Don't Know Why](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/troubleshooting#tests-are-failing-and-you-don-t-know-why)* recommends running Jest like so:

```
node --inspect-brk node_modules/.bin/jest --runInBand src/pages/login/__tests__/login-page.integration.test.js
```

Turning on "Pause on exceptions" in devtools is very helpful.